# Changing file association to a new version with the same .exe name

Tags: windows-xp, file-association

I installed a new version of a software (Toad for SQL Server 4.6 Beta), keeping the old version (4.5 Freeware) too. Now I want to associate .sql files with the new version. I show the path to the new .exe file in the new folder. However, probably because the .exe filenames of both versions are the same, it keeps the association with the old one. Any ideas?

OS: Windows XP SP2

Comment: See:
http://superuser.com/questions/608149/how-do-i-change-the-default-program-aka-file-assocation-when-the-program-has-m

for a similiar question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a daft question but have you tried switching it to some arbitrary application (say, Notepad) and then switching it back to the new one?

Comment: Yes I did. No good..

Answer (score 1):

you could try changing the extension of the old exe program - such as version45.exe to version45.old

This would then keep both programs but only leave one progrtam able to complete the sql tasks

Comment: I tried that too. When I rename the old .exe to 'toad.exe.old', it doesn't appear in the 'open with' list anymore. However, when I show the path of the new .exe 'toad.exe', it does not get accepted. Probably because the name 'toad.exe' still exists in the registry, but it can't find it in the defined path. I think I need to change something in the registry but I don't know what.. Or maybe I will change the new .exe to 'toad46.exe'. But I'm sure there will be some inconsistencies somewhere...