# How do I change the default program (aka file assocation) when the program has moved?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-association

In Windows 7, if I have already associated a program, say `Notepad2.exe`, with a filetype, say `.txt` then moving the path to `Notepad2.exe` (e.g., moving the folder) breaks the association.  The problem I have is that I do not see a way to fix the association.

The normal methods of choosing the filetype association, through right-click > properties or through the control panel, do not work.  When you reach the "Choose the Program you want to use to open this file" window you can try browsing for the `.exe` you want, but after pointing it to the new path, the program `Notepad2.exe` will not in fact be there when you return to the "Choose the Program you want to use to open this file:" window.

If you rename `Notepad2.exe` to something else, like `Notepad2a.exe` then you can associate it as normal.  So apparently the problem was that Windows assumes the name of the `.exe` identifies the program.  Since it obviously remembers the old path to `Notepad2.exe` one could interpret this behavior as silently complaining that it doesn't want to remember two `Notepad2.exe`s with different paths.

Using the registry I have tried deleting the remaining associations to `Notepad2.exe` (e.g., using this answer https://superuser.com/a/49617/223560).  I have also adjusted the registry entry for the MRU list to remove mention of it.  But this was not enough to make windows 'forget' about it.  Since this is a portable application, there is no uninstaller to help make windows forget about it.

Is there a way to fix this mess?  Changing the name of `Notepad2.exe` or creating a 2nd copy/shortcut with a different name is not an acceptable solution to me.  I want to make it work like it normally should.

*Edit:*
Poking around the registry gives some clues.  The registry keys under `OpenWithList` contains keys with values like `Notepad2.exe` --- just the name and not the path.   In the registry under `UserChoice` there is a key `Progid` with value `Applications\Notepad2.exe`.  That doesn't look like a path, and I'm not sure how windows decides what path that corresponds to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seemed to have found it:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\Notepad2.exe\shell\open\command`

Edit this key to the new path.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix this by using the Registry.

We start by locating the filetype in question

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt
```

Looking at this key you will see that it is linked with another key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile
```

Follow a little further and you will see the key that controls which program opens

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/3d9596b/.cygwin#L13)

Comment: The thing is, that registry key still points to ordinary `Notepad.exe` even when the `Notepad2.exe` association is working under normal circumstances.  Messing with it now seems like a further kludge.